Geometry nodes inverse curve trim
I need to make curve corner trim like on image below (green lines). Any help appreciated.



I have no idea what you mean.

I need to get only green lines like on image (Right up corner)

This setup stores on points center position and 50% distance to two neighbors (centers of segments connecting the points), spawns triple-point curves "o-o-o" on those points (it's important the midpoint is in origin), then sets the endpoints to a linear interpolation between stored halfway positions and stored center position:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror

Hi, thank You for help. By the way is there a quick solution to inverse it? Because I'd like to separate corners from middle edges, but keep both

@Mateusz88 for scaling mid segments you can just split edges and then scale elements

Thank you it works
